# How to find a list item with an id in a list of items?

Tags: javascript, html, list, html-lists

I have a list of keywords that I want to filter based on `<li id="newKeyword">`:

```
<ul id="keywordList">
  <li></li>
  <li id="newKeyword"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

When I click a button, the function `showNewKeywords()` triggers:

```
function showNewKeywords() {
  // Declare variables
  var ul, li;

  ul = document.getElementById("keywordList");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');


  // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't have the li ID
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {

    // Find id of each li within the list
    
  }
}
```

I have difficulties looping through the list of `li` tags to find the ones with the `id`. I tried the `getElementById` method, but that goes through the entire file (I think).

Any tips on how to filter through a list of `li` based on the `li id`?

Thanks so much!

Edit: fixed typos.

Comment: classes? I see no classes. PS, `a = ` don't waste global scope with variables.

Comment: `a.textContent || a.innerText` why? use just the preferred `a.textContent;`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I've edited the post to fix typos. Please take another look :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you loop you need to get `li` element, I assigned to `a` variable, and get its `id` put it inside `txtValue` and test for  that if `is not equal (!=)` then remove it with affect it a style of `display:none`:

```js
function showNewKeywords() {
  // Declare variables
  var ul, li;

  ul = document.getElementById("keywordList");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');


  // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't have the li ID
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    //vvvv
    a = li[i];
    // My main problem here
    //a = "find id of each li within the list";
    txtValue = a.id;

    // This is a secondary problem but I'll figure it out
    if (txtValue!='newKeyword') {
      a.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="keywordList">
  <li></li>
  <li id="newKeyword"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
<button onclick="showNewKeywords()">show New Keywords</button>
```

PS: choose better naming of variables:
instead of `a` name it with `currentLI` which has more sense, and also for `txtValue` replace it with `idOfCurrLI`.